# ffmpeg apad duration slightly different

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to add an audio to a silent video, and the audio is shorter than the video, so I want to add silence to the end of the audio and make sure they have same duration. I use below command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:0]apad" -c:v copy -shortest output.mp4
```

but the output durations are slightly different

1. Am I making any mistake here?
2. Is there a way to make them exactly same?

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_type,duration,start_pts,start_time -sexagesimal output.mp4
[STREAM]
codec_type=audio
start_pts=0
start_time=0:00:00.000000
duration=0:00:03.621995
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
codec_type=video
start_pts=0
start_time=0:00:00.000000
duration=0:00:03.640000
[/STREAM]
```

input file info

```
▶ ffmpeg -i video.mp4                                                                                   
ffmpeg version 4.4-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:03.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 394 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1080x1920, 390 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]


▶ ffmpeg  -i audio.mp3                                                                                     
ffmpeg version 4.4-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'audio.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TCM             : A
    TT1             : xxx
    title           : yyy
    encoded_by      : ProTranscoderTool (Apple MP3 v1
  Duration: 00:00:02.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 271 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 265 kb/s
```

Comment: Take a look at [gyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800185/my-ffmpeg-output-always-add-extra-30s-of-silence-at-the-end#55804507)